# Increase font size in emeditor user prompt window

Tags: emeditor

i am using the following code in one of the emeditor macros to give data by user.
sFind = prompt( "This macro extracts lines that do contain any of the specified multiple strings separated by |:", "" );
if( sFind == "" )
{ Quit(); }

the problem with the above code is font size is very small.
is it possible to increase the font size to 20 and also single line text to be converted as multiline text.
please help me.

Comment: You can't change the font size for a particular dialog box. You could change the font size of the whole Windows system from Windows Settings, but that can affect all other windows. I am not sure what you mean by single line text to be converted as multiline text.

Comment: i want to increase the text window height to 2 times single line height.

Comment: i need regex to replace .*(?=[A-Z]:) with empty space using the macro line document.selection.Replace in the whole document. how to write document.selection.Replace(".*(?=[A-Z]:)", "", eeFindReplaceQuiet | eeReplaceAll);

Comment: Please don't mix several questions. Please focus one question at a time.

Comment: first question you said it is not possible. hence i asked second question.

Comment: with trial and error i found the solution. document.selection.Replace(".*(?=[A-Z]:)","",eeFindNext | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp, eeExFindRegexBoost);